# Vectorising 3d array

Tags: matlab, vectorization

I am trying to vectorise a `for` loop. I have a set of coordinates listed in a `[68x200]` matrix called `plt2`, and I have another set of coordinates listed in a `[400x1]` matrix called `trans1`. I want to create a three dimensional array called `dist1`, where in `dist1(:,:,1)` I have all of the values of `plt2` with the first value of `trans1` subtracted, all the way through to the end of `trans1`. I have a for loop like this which works but is very slow:

```
for i=1:source_points;
    dist1(:,:,i)=plt2-trans1(i,1);
end
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3):

If I understood correctly, this can be easily solved with `bsxfun`:

```
dist1 = bsxfun(@minus, plt2, shiftdim(trans1,-2));
```

Or, if speed is important, use this equivalent version (thanks to @chappjc), which seems to be much faster:

```
dist1 = bsxfun(@minus, plt2, reshape(trans1,1,1,[]));
```

In general, `bsxfun` is a very useful function for cases like this. Its behaviour can be summarized as follows: for any singleton dimension of any of its two input arrays, it applies an "implicit" `for` loop to the other array along the same dimension. See the [doc](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) for further details.

Comment: @Dan But `trans` is 400x1 and it needs to be reshaped into 1x1x400... With -1 it gets reshaped into 1x400

Comment: @Dan Thanks anyway for your willingness to help!

Comment: Nicely done, +1.  FYI to anyone, `shiftdim(trans1,-2)` is the same as both `permute(R,[3 2 1])` and `reshape(R,[1 1 400])` since `trans` is 400x1.  Whatever is most intuitive to you...

Comment: ... most intuitive or _fastest_: on my computer, the `reshape` version wins hands down.

Comment: That makes sense since `reshape` does not modify the data buffer, just the dimensions (when it detects the possibility to work in-place).

Comment: @chappjc That's interesting. Can you be more specific? What's the data buffer?

Comment: Consider a matrix `a=rand(10,2)`. Run `format debug` and `disp(a)`, make a note of `pr`.  That's the pointer to the buffer holding the data. `m` and `n` are the rows and columns, of course.  Now do `a = reshape(a,[2 10])`.  Note that only `m` and `n` change, not `pr`.  This doesn't prove that MATLAB doesn't re-write the buffer, but it clearly kept it in-place. By virtue of the semantics of `reshape`, it think it is safe to assume the data didn't get re-written.  Interesting supplemental reference: http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2007/03/22/in-place-operations-on-data/#13

Comment: Thanks for the detailed and in-depth info!

Answer (score 0):

Vectorizing is a good first optimization, and is usually much easier than going all in writing your own compiled mex-function (in c).

However, the golden middle-way for power users is Matlab Coder (this also applies to slightly harder problems than the one posted, where vectorization is more or less impossible). First, create a small m-file function around the slow code, in your case:

```
function dist1 = do_some_stuff(source_points,dist1,plt2,trans1)
for i=1:source_points;
    dist1(:,:,i)=plt2-trans1(i,1);
end
```

Then create a simple wrapper function which calls do_some_stuff as well as defines the inputs. This file should really be only 5 rows, with only the bare essentials needed. Matlab Coder uses the wrapper function to understand what typical proper inputs to do_some_stuff are.

You can now fire up the Matlab Coder gui from the Apps section and simply add do_some_stuff under Entry-Point Files. Press Autodefine types and select your wrapper function. Go to build and press build, and you are good to go! This approach usually bumps up the execution speed substantially with almost no effort.

BR
Magnus